# Can you work out the Covariance(A,B) by knowing Covariance(A,M) and Covariance(B,M)

Tags: covariance

I have the foloowing information:
A (stock A) 
B (stock B)
M (market index)
cov(M,M) = 5 
cov(A,M) = 6
cov(B,M) = 2

how do i make a "(2 X 2)-CoVariance matrix" of A and B? 
 - i need to find:
                   1) cov(A,B)
                   2) cov(A,A) = variance,A
                   3) cov(B,B) = variance,B

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. M can be correlated with both, A and B, but A may be uncorrelated with B. However, it may be possible to derive some bounds on that value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine the variances of $A$ or $B$, or their covariance, from the information that you have. The closest you can come is *lower* bounds
on the variances based on the fact that
$$\frac{|\operatorname{cov}(A,M)|}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(A)\operatorname{var}(M)}} \leq 1 \implies 
\operatorname{var}(A) \geq \frac{(\operatorname{cov}(A,M))^2}{\operatorname{var}(M)}$$
and similarly for $\operatorname{var}(B)$.